# Backing up database with SMO

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

I have created a class to backup a database, the code is:

```
public bool BackupDatabase(string databasename)
        {
            bool success = false;

            try
            {
                Backup dbBackup = new Backup();

                string SqlInstance = @"SERVER\INSTANCE";
                string User = ExtractPureUsername(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
                string BackupLocation = @"\\SERVER\FOLDER\BACKUPTEST_" + User.ToString() + ".bak";

                Server srv = new Server(SqlInstance);

                dbBackup.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
                dbBackup.Database = databasename;
                dbBackup.Devices.AddDevice(BackupLocation, DeviceType.File);
                dbBackup.BackupSetName = "Test database backup";
                dbBackup.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(10);
                dbBackup.Initialize = false;
                dbBackup.PercentComplete += CompletionStatusInPercent;
                dbBackup.Complete += Backup_Completed;

                dbBackup.SqlBackup(srv);

                success = true;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

            return success;
        }
```

This runs through, and I get the error:

> Cannot open backup device - Operating System error 5

If I were to run the backup on the instance referenced, in SSMS, I can backup to the Bakup location that is specified. So I am presuming that the error is occuring becuase the backup is being initiated as the user that is running the C# program, and SQL server is having none of it. Is there a way to specify which user to run the backup as?

Comment: The backup is always performed under the user of the SQL Server service; it isn't possible to change or impersonate this. If you have a working command in SSMS for the same instance, then SMO is simply constructing something different from what you're expecting. Double check this with a profiler trace if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to set the correct file name as *local path* on the SQL Server machine. So for instance instead of `\\ServerName\Whatever`, use `c:\Whatever`. Make sure the file name you generate doesn't contain illegal characters, like `\` or something.

Comment: Thanks - Stupid error on my part, thanks for the nudge. Was using UNC, changing it to the local path sorts the issue.